# Access Ubuntu/Apache WordPress on a LAN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server, wordpress

I have successfully installed WP 4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

From the Linux machine I can access the WP site by browsing to    asus/wp_site_name.  When I go to a PC or a Mac on the same LAN and browse to    asus/wp_site_name I get: err_name_not_resolved.  If I put the local    IP address as the url (192.168.1.121/wp_site_name) the WP site comes    up, but the CSS clearly does not load.  In the console I see 19    errors that say: Failed to load resource: nwt::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED    http://localhost/wp_site_name/wp_content/themes/singlepage/...

Ultimately, I would like to just browse to wp_site_name instead of asus/wp_site_name.

Here are my files:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName asus
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wp_site_name
        ServerName wp_site_name
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apach2/ports.conf:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   asus
```

/etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf

```
ServerName localhost
ServerName asus
```

iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:a6:86:ad  
          inet addr:192.168.1.121  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3285:a9ff:fea6:86ad/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17978192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11846889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9191921586 (9.1 GB)  TX bytes:2375745317 (2.3 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1961720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1961720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:328646424 (328.6 MB)  TX bytes:328646424 (328.6 MB)
```

Finally, I have my WordPress directories wide open:

```
/var/www/html/wp_site_name/wp-content/themes/singlepage$ ls -l
total 696
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1704 Apr 12 01:41 404.php
drwxrwxrwx 6 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 admin
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    184 Apr 12 01:41 archive.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   4708 Apr 12 01:41 comments.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1605 Apr 12 01:41 content-article.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    895 Apr 12 01:41 content-blog-list.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    952 Apr 12 01:41 content-home.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 css
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   3902 Apr 12 01:41 editor-style.css
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   5716 Apr 12 01:41 featured-content.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 fonts
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    326 Apr 12 01:41 footer-featured.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1969 Apr 12 01:41 footer.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    340 Apr 12 01:41 front-page.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1221 Apr 12 01:41 functions.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   2088 Apr 12 01:41 header-featured.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   2084 Apr 12 01:41 header-page.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1806 Apr 12 01:41 header.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    484 Apr 12 01:41 home.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 images
drwxrwxrwx 2 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 includes
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    148 Apr 12 01:41 index.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 js
drwxrwxrwx 2 groupEd groupEd   4096 Apr 14 04:37 languages
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd  18551 Apr 12 01:41 options.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   3358 Apr 12 01:41 page.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   3983 Apr 12 01:41 readme.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    381 Apr 12 01:41 rtl.css
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd 509899 Apr 12 01:41 screenshot.png
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1384 Apr 12 01:41 search.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   1108 Apr 12 01:41 sidebar-blog.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd    383 Apr 12 01:41 sidebar-page.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd   2698 Apr 12 01:41 single.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 groupEd groupEd  43902 Apr 12 01:41 style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is caused by the fact that no computer on your network knows the name of your server, but the server itself. You have to add similar `/etc/hosts` records to all of them or even set up a DNS server.

The second looks more like a configuration problem in your WP, cause I see it trying to get static files at localhost even when you enter another address. I haven't seen WP for many years and can't tell where exactly to look for this setting.

Comment: Thank you. The first issue seemed to resolve itself. I made no changes and now the site pops up when I browse to asus/wp_site_name. On the second issue, I followed permission instructions on WordPress Codex [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) for hardening. Next, I went into Settings\General\WordPress Address URL and changed it to http://asus/wp_site_name and it worked across the whole network.